# Rxjs combine Observable of arrays

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I show an overview of dates, (I simplified my example)

```
someArray$: Observable<Date[]> = of(
new Date(2019, 11, 1),
new Date(2019, 11, 2),
new Date(2019, 11, 3));
```

Then I make a call to the backend and get some data like this:

```
anotherArray$: Observable<MyClass[]> = of(
{date: new Date(2019, 11, 1), active: true},
{date: new Date(2019, 11, 2), active: false},
{date: new Date(2019, 11, 3), active: false});
```

Now I already show someArray$ with an *ngFor in my template so I thought I could combine them somehow without subscribing and then use the boolean value from the second array to visualise activity.

Comment: What do you mean by "combine them"? If the template already displays the dates from the first observable, and you don't want to change your template, why do you get the second observable, which contains the same information as the first one?

Comment: I make a call where I get the second Array from and then I want to use the boolean to make it active or inactive.

Comment: try combineLatest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this steps:

1. change your someArray$ to:

```
someArray$ = of([
  { date: new Date(2019, 11, 1) },
  { date: new Date(2019, 11, 2) },
  { date: new Date(2019, 11, 3) }
]);
```

2. Merge the two observables:

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs';

dates$ = merge(
  this.someArray$,
  this.anotherArray$
);
```

3. Bind dates$ with an *ngFor in your template instead of someArray$

---

Here is a [StackBlitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-first-then-second-merge) (notice the active column values changing after 5 seconds)

Comment: I see that merge will get deprecated what would it be when that happens?

Comment: Where do you see that? In the official docs of RxJS it doesn't say anything, it's written as *stable* - https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/merge

Comment: oh it's when I import it from elsewhere nvm ;)

Comment: any idea how to do this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jvbvhx?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: The example project you've uploaded isn't working, it is giving me this error in the console - *ERROR
Error: Cannot read property 'activity' of undefined*.

Comment: my bad, didn't know I changed the original stackblitz

Comment: What r u trying to achieve?

Comment: I tried to add a boolean 'first' if the previous had 'activity' true and the current false. And add the boolean 'last' if the next doesn't have the boolean 'activity' false but the current has false. But I already gave up on it.